# Programatically waking up the OS from energy saving or screen saver

Tags: c++, qt, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Supose my Qt application is running in background and I want to wake up the operating system when the screen saver is active or the monitor is blank for energy saving.

Is there any way to do it under Linux? concretely I would like to do it for a Raspberry Pi under Raspbian but a cross-platform method using Qt will be better.

Comment: I am completely suprised. Nobody knows how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're ok with it never going into sleep mode in the first place, but this is what I use:

```
sudo leafpad /etc/kbd/config
    change BLANK_TIME=0
    change POWERDOWN_TIME=0
sudo leafpad /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
    Add line: @xset s noblank
    Add line: @xset s off
    Add line: @xset -dpms
```

**Edit** Just realized how old this question was. I hope I ended your 20 months of waiting and page refreshing.

Comment: Actually I solved this 20 months ago, so as an action of gratitude to you, I will mark your answer as the right answer. Btw, I did something similar as you have posted. Your help is appreciated, and I hope we can chat again in 20 months from now.

Comment: Thanks! and I'll look forward to it!